# how can I center a tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, minipage

I was looking for the way to center in the page the following tikzpicture (I am using Overleaf). However I cannot get it, It is shown moved to the right part... any ideas??

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \centering
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{1.7\textwidth}
    \centering
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
            \node (A) at (-12,-2)  {N5xx};
            \node (B) at (-10,4)   {N612};
            \node (C) at (-5,7)    {N614};
            \node (D) at (0,4)     {N624};
            \node (E) at (2,-2)    {N7070};
            \node (F) at (-1,-8)   {N7071};
            \node (G) at (-9,-8)   {Others};
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
                    center coordinate every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
                     % every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}
                     ]
            \path [->] (A) edge[bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node {$5$}  (B);
            \path [->] (A) edge[bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node {$3$}  (C);
            \path [->] (A) edge[bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node {$4$}  (D);
            \path [->] (A) edge[bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node {$3$}  (E);
            \path [->] (A) edge[bend right = 25, blue,very thick]  node {$3$}  (F);
            \path [->] (A) edge[bend right = 25, blue,very thick]  node {$3$}  (G);
            \path [->] (A) edge[loop left = 25, blue,very thick]   node {$3$}  (A);

            \path [->] (B) edge[loop left = 15, red,very thick]   node {$5$}  (B);
            \path [->] (B) edge[bend right = 25, red,very thick]   node {$3$}  (A);
            \path [->] (B) edge[bend left = 15, red,very thick]   node {$3$}  (C);
            \path [->] (B) edge[bend left = 15, red,very thick]   node {$4$}  (D);
            \path [->] (B) edge[bend left = 15, red,very thick]   node {$3$}  (E);
            \path [->] (B) edge[bend right = 25, red,very thick]  node {$3$}  (F);
            \path [->] (B) edge[bend right = 25, red,very thick]  node {$3$}  (G);

            \path [->] (C) edge[green,very thick]   node {$3$}  (A);
            \path [->] (C) edge[bend right = 30, green,very thick]   node {$5$} (B);
            \path [->] (C) edge[loop above = 15, green,very thick]  node {$3$}  (C);
            \path [->] (C) edge[bend left = 30, green,very thick]   node {$4$}  (D);
            \path [->] (C) edge[ green,very thick]   node {$3$}  (E);
            \path [->] (C) edge[bend left = 5, green,very thick]  node {$3$}  (F);
            \path [->] (C) edge[bend right = 5, green,very thick]  node {$3$}   (G);

            \path [->] (D) edge[bend left = 25, orange,very thick]    node {$3$}  (A);
            \path [->] (D) edge[bend left = 15, orange,very thick]    node {$5$}  (B);
            \path [->] (D) edge[bend right = 15,orange,very thick]   node {$3$}  (C);
            \path [->] (D) edge[loop right = 15,orange,very thick]   node {$4$}  (D);
            \path [->] (D) edge[bend left = 15, orange,very thick]    node {$3$}  (E);
            \path [->] (D) edge[bend left = 25,orange,very thick]   node {$3$}  (F);
            \path [->] (D) edge[bend left = 25,orange,very thick]   node {$3$}  (G);

            \path [->]  (E) edge[bend left = 25, purple!50 ,very thick]    node {$3$}  (A);
            \path [->]  (E) edge[bend left = 15, purple!50,very thick]    node {$5$}  (B);
            \path [->]  (E) edge[bend right = 15,purple!50,very thick]    node {$3$}  (C);
            \path [->]  (E) edge[bend right = 15,purple!50,very thick]    node {$4$}  (D);
            \path [->]  (E) edge[loop right = 15, purple!50,very thick]    node {$3$}  (E);
            \path [->]  (E) edge[bend left = 25,purple!50,very thick]     node {$3$}  (F);
            \path [->]  (E) edge[bend left = 25,purple!50,very thick]     node {$3$}  (G);

             \path [->]  (F) edge[bend left = 25, very thick]    node {$3$}  (A);
            \path [->]  (F) edge[bend left = 15, very thick]    node {$5$}  (B);
            \path [->]  (F) edge[bend right = 15,very thick]    node {$3$}  (C);
            \path [->]  (F) edge[bend right = 15, very thick]    node {$4$}  (D);
            \path [->]  (F) edge[bend right = 15, very thick]    node {$3$}  (E);
            \path [->]  (F) edge[loop right = 25,very thick]     node {$3$}  (F);
            \path [->]  (F) edge[bend left = 25,very thick]     node {$3$}  (G);


        \end{scope}

        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}



        \end{minipage}
     \end{document}
```

Comment: Just put the tikzpicture within a figure environment. `\begin{figure} \centering \begin{tikzpicture} ... \end{tikzpicture} \end{figure}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, I changed the `minipage` width to `1\textwidth`, not `1.7\textwidth`.  Then, I eliminated the `center` environment, as it was basically redundant with `\centering`.  I then placed the image in a `\makebox[0pt]{}`, so that margin violations would be ignored.  I added a `\par` at the end just to emphasize that `\centering` needs to have the paragraph end to take effect.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \centering
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{1\textwidth}
    \centering
    \makebox[0pt]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[every node/.style={circle,thick,draw}]
            \node (A) at (-12,-2)  {N5xx};
            \node (B) at (-10,4)   {N612};
            \node (C) at (-5,7)    {N614};
            \node (D) at (0,4)     {N624};
            \node (E) at (2,-2)    {N7070};
            \node (F) at (-1,-8)   {N7071};
            \node (G) at (-9,-8)   {Others};
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[>={Stealth[black]},
                    center coordinate every node/.style={fill=white,circle},
                     % every edge/.style={draw=red,very thick}
                     ]
            \path [->] (A) edge[bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node {$5$}  (B);
            \path [->] (A) edge[bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node {$3$}  (C);
            \path [->] (A) edge[bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node {$4$}  (D);
            \path [->] (A) edge[bend left = 15, blue,very thick]   node {$3$}  (E);
            \path [->] (A) edge[bend right = 25, blue,very thick]  node {$3$}  (F);
            \path [->] (A) edge[bend right = 25, blue,very thick]  node {$3$}  (G);
            \path [->] (A) edge[loop left = 25, blue,very thick]   node {$3$}  (A);

            \path [->] (B) edge[loop left = 15, red,very thick]   node {$5$}  (B);
            \path [->] (B) edge[bend right = 25, red,very thick]   node {$3$}  (A);
            \path [->] (B) edge[bend left = 15, red,very thick]   node {$3$}  (C);
            \path [->] (B) edge[bend left = 15, red,very thick]   node {$4$}  (D);
            \path [->] (B) edge[bend left = 15, red,very thick]   node {$3$}  (E);
            \path [->] (B) edge[bend right = 25, red,very thick]  node {$3$}  (F);
            \path [->] (B) edge[bend right = 25, red,very thick]  node {$3$}  (G);

            \path [->] (C) edge[green,very thick]   node {$3$}  (A);
            \path [->] (C) edge[bend right = 30, green,very thick]   node {$5$} (B);
            \path [->] (C) edge[loop above = 15, green,very thick]  node {$3$}  (C);
            \path [->] (C) edge[bend left = 30, green,very thick]   node {$4$}  (D);
            \path [->] (C) edge[ green,very thick]   node {$3$}  (E);
            \path [->] (C) edge[bend left = 5, green,very thick]  node {$3$}  (F);
            \path [->] (C) edge[bend right = 5, green,very thick]  node {$3$}   (G);

            \path [->] (D) edge[bend left = 25, orange,very thick]    node {$3$}  (A);
            \path [->] (D) edge[bend left = 15, orange,very thick]    node {$5$}  (B);
            \path [->] (D) edge[bend right = 15,orange,very thick]   node {$3$}  (C);
            \path [->] (D) edge[loop right = 15,orange,very thick]   node {$4$}  (D);
            \path [->] (D) edge[bend left = 15, orange,very thick]    node {$3$}  (E);
            \path [->] (D) edge[bend left = 25,orange,very thick]   node {$3$}  (F);
            \path [->] (D) edge[bend left = 25,orange,very thick]   node {$3$}  (G);

            \path [->]  (E) edge[bend left = 25, purple!50 ,very thick]    node {$3$}  (A);
            \path [->]  (E) edge[bend left = 15, purple!50,very thick]    node {$5$}  (B);
            \path [->]  (E) edge[bend right = 15,purple!50,very thick]    node {$3$}  (C);
            \path [->]  (E) edge[bend right = 15,purple!50,very thick]    node {$4$}  (D);
            \path [->]  (E) edge[loop right = 15, purple!50,very thick]    node {$3$}  (E);
            \path [->]  (E) edge[bend left = 25,purple!50,very thick]     node {$3$}  (F);
            \path [->]  (E) edge[bend left = 25,purple!50,very thick]     node {$3$}  (G);

             \path [->]  (F) edge[bend left = 25, very thick]    node {$3$}  (A);
            \path [->]  (F) edge[bend left = 15, very thick]    node {$5$}  (B);
            \path [->]  (F) edge[bend right = 15,very thick]    node {$3$}  (C);
            \path [->]  (F) edge[bend right = 15, very thick]    node {$4$}  (D);
            \path [->]  (F) edge[bend right = 15, very thick]    node {$3$}  (E);
            \path [->]  (F) edge[loop right = 25,very thick]     node {$3$}  (F);
            \path [->]  (F) edge[bend left = 25,very thick]     node {$3$}  (G);


        \end{scope}

        \end{tikzpicture}%
    }\par



        \end{minipage}
     \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Javiss Glad to have helped. Welcome to the site!

Comment: Thanks! I am struggling with another issue : I would like to know how can I change the weights' colour because actually if the weights has the same color as the edge, it cannot be really appreciated. I want every weight in black.------ edited: just got it: node [black, fill = white]